# PHP class to validate javascript syntax

Tags: php, javascript

Do you have any ideas where to find a PHP class (library) which can validate JavaScript syntax?

**Result**: it seems that there is no such library which is available to download, so the only solution is to write own. Thank you all.

Comment: That's far from trivial. Why do you need this? There might be a better solution for it.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) about what questions not to ask.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Before running JS optimizer I would like to validate the code in order to be sure that it will fine and in case it is corrupted some notification will be shown to the developer.

Comment: @Carrie Kendall thank you for pointing to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice class which is a wrapper to the ubiquitous (for JS validation) JSLint -  http://www.overflow.biz/blog/lang/en-us/2010/07/07/jslint-php-class/

It does require that you can execute binaries on you're server as you require JSLint itself of course.

EDIT:

There is also a (very old) php-based parser - http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2009/11/jparser-and-jtokenizer-released/ - I used it a long time ago not for a while!

Comment: I am interested in library which does not rely on binaries or services, otherwise the problem can be solved easier with online service.

Comment: Archives on the page seem to be broken. But thank you anyway.